# In TYPO3 6.1, how to use header_layout from standard language only?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x, tsconfig

I use the `header_layout` field to wrap content elements with css classes.

```
tt_content.text.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject=CASE
tt_content.text.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject{
    key.field = header_layout
    default=TEXT
    default.value=|
    1=TEXT
    1.value=<aside class="box clearfix">|</aside>
}
```

Now, the selection is only applied in the default language, not in localisations.

How do I tell TYPO3 to look only at the header_layout field from the standard language (0), and how do I consequently hide that field in localisations?

And: the use of header_layout is an often-practiced workaround, obviously. Is there a field designed for that use (assigning custom TS to individual content elements) in TYPO3 >= 6.0?

Comment: You can use `[globalVar = GP:L = 0]...code...[GLOBAL]`

Comment: I want to use the default language field always, so the other way round, I can't see the use for a condition

Answer (score 0):

To just wrap a content element with other HTML that the default you can use the frames and indention dropdown of the appearance tab.

You add an entry via PageTSConfig:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content{
    section_frame {
        addItems {
            100 = My new Frame
        }
    }
}
```

And define the corresponding rendering in TypoScript:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    key.field = section_frame
    100 < .66
    100.30.value = <div class="my-css-class">|</div>
}
```

As how to exclude it from localozation, Im not quite sure. Should wotk fine if your localized records have the same frame.

Comment: This the same principle as the use of header_layout - it's just a different abandonned field you are using. Also, the proper localised use is essention to my question / problem

Comment: "essential" not essention :-)

Comment: Thats true, but I feel like the frame is the more propper place to do this. Anyhow, do you have concidered to use fluidcontent and create a fluidcontent element for your wrapper, insert the normal content element and translate ist. That way you would have the same wrapper for every language and dont need to use section_frame nor header_layout?

Comment: I will switch to flux, but now I am looking for a non-extension based, robust, vanilla solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is supported by TypoScript, but you could use l10n_mode exclude on the header_layout field:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['header_layout']['l10n_mode'] = 'exclude';
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['header_layout']['l10n_display'] = 'defaultAsReadOnly';
```

This excludes the field from translation and displays it as readonly in the localized versions.

See all options here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#l10n-mode

As initially stated, this is untested - I don't know if it works from TypoScript context.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz, I've tried adding it to AdditionalConfiguration.php (for testing, of course) either starting with `$GLOBALS['TCA']`or `$TCA`. It wouldn't hide the field in the backend, though, no luck.

Comment: Did you clear the configuration cache afterwards? It would be possible that is has no effect in TS, but it has to work in TCEFORM.

Comment: Yes, and ext:uncache is running as well. (Sorry), which is the correct way to put into  AdditionalConfiguration.php, $GLOBALS['TCA']or $TCA?

Comment: The correct way is using an extTables script. AdditionalConfiguration is only for enivorment-specific configuration (e.g. different db credentials for development). The "extTablesDefinitionScript" is defined in LocalConfiguration.php.

Comment: I understand, I've added it to `/typo3conf/extTables.php` which is defined in `LocalConfiguration.php`. In both ways, with and without $GLOBALS - unfortunately, no reaction in the backend

Comment: Check your changes in the configuration section of your backend. Select the TCA and check if the changes to header_layout are applied. If they are not, then something with your extTables is not working.

Comment: Yes, the setting is reflected in TCA. Now I see: it removes the label only, not the field: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11320047/Google%20Chrome.jpg

Comment: sorry, now I notice it does seem to do the trick. the default language setting prevails. So the TS part *does* seem to work - while the TCA-Part has still the issue that it only removes the label